# Pg Admin import csv issues

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, pgadmin

hello I am trying to import a csv file into one of my tables in my pg admin database but keep this reoccurring error.

```
COPY CO_ROADS
FROM 'C:\Users\Geog\Documents\corut.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV_HEADER;
```

ERROR: malformed array literal: "2.07"
DETAIL: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
CONTEXT: COPY co_roads, line 2, column ACRES: "2.07"

This is confusing since the data type of the column is an integer.

any advice? thank you!

I tried getting rid of unnecessary columns and using a comma as a delimiter for the csv. No avail though.

Comment: 1) What is the error? **Add it as text to the question text**. 2) Though from [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html): *COPY with a file name instructs the PostgreSQL server to directly read from or write to a file. The file must be accessible by the PostgreSQL user (the user ID the server runs as) and the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server.*. I'm guessing you are running into a issue related to that. 3) Are you using this [Import/Export](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/8.4/import_export_data.html). If not you should be.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is export a csv from a Pg_admin database from one PC to a pg_admin database in another PC. I don't know of any alternatives to do this other than the copy command. thanks!

Comment: You managed to pretty much ignore everything I posted in my comment. You want advice, yet don't want to follow up on it. When you do, then add to your question text the results.

Comment: Yew im runnig import/export

Comment: The error is telling you the problem you are trying to stuff a non-array value into an array column. Best guess  is you have an indexing mismatch between the columns in the CSV file and those in the table and per [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html): *For COPY FROM, each field in the file is inserted, in order, into the specified column.*  You need to compare the columns in the CSV file and those in the table to make sure your entering the values in the correct order and of the correct type to match the order and type in the table.

Comment: But the column is not a non-array value. its an integer which is driving me nuts.

Comment: Take the error message as the truth. The value(2.07) from the CSV is an integer that is being inserted into a column in the database that is an array.  Look at the table there will be an array column in it. As I said before the issue is the fields and their associated values are not being presented in the correct order for the columns in the table. `COPY` will not use the HEADER to automatically match the CSV field order to the table field order.